# CLion not debugging one of my targets - immediate `Process finished with exit code 0`

Tags: c++, debugging, clion

I'm on a Mac using Clang 6.  I have a project with a few targets and they all worked as expected until recently when suddenly I could not debug my unit tests.  I give the command to debug and it immediately comes back with

```
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

I can `run` the target from within CLion (or outside of it) and it runs as expected.   I can debug other targets as expected.

CLion is building the un-debug-able target as expected.   I've created additional CLion configurations with the program and none of them will debug it correctly - whether set up as a "normal" app or as a google test app in CLion.

I don't have my CLion config files in version control and CLion's local history isn't available on them - the option is greyed out.

I don't know what information to post here and I'm hoping someone else has seen something like this or can guess what I might have done.  I've rebooted my computer as well as "invalidate caches and restart" in CLion.  None of them had any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `preferences`, `build execution and deployment`, `Toolchains`, `debugger`, switching from `bundled lldb` to `bundled gdb`, debugging the program (may not have been required), then switching back to `bundled lldb` fixed the problem.

I have no idea what the actual problem was or how this fixed it, but it did.

Comment: I don't know why this happens, but it happens to me very frequently and switching back and forth solves it for some reason.

Comment: @M2X I haven't run into this since I posted the question/solution, but glad it helped someone.   It was VERY frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem today and managed to fixed it. For someone like me to not waste time I'm leaving the solution.

Just launch lldb with your executable in the terminal. I don't know why this solves the problem but that leads to macOS popping up the security alert which lets me reset a possibly-accidentally disabled access to the executable by the debugger.